# How can I create a COM object for register as limited user?

Tags: com, atl

I am creating a project in vs2010, it is intended to be installed per-user but I need to include a COM object (in a dll, I'm using ATL). The thing is I can only make the DLL register with admin privileges, but my installer doesn't require admin privileges and the com registration fails.

This is what I found:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2005/05/29/423000.aspx

I did that modifications, changed the .rgs files from HKCR to HKCU, and modified the DllRegisterServer code to override HKCR by HKCU\Software\Classes

But I'm getting the same error: 0x8002801c using regsvr32 (as limited user), and the installer also gives me an error. Is there something else needed to create per-user COM objects?

Thans.

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to find out what keys it is writing to.  If you only see HKCU being written then you really do need to allow the user to write his own registry keys.

Comment: `regsvr32 /i` registers using `DllInstall` instead of `DllRegisterServer`, with the HKCU (as opposed to default HKCR) option. With the current state of ATL, implementation of `DllInstall` is included in standard project template.

Answer (score 0):

Create manifest file that references DLL. Check out [this tool](http://www.mazecomputer.com/sxsv2.htm) for painless manifest generation

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, you can enable **Per-user Redirection** option in the project properties > Linker > General.

I didn't need to change modify the rgs file.

To register COM .exe, use /RegServerPerUser flag. The normal /RegServer flag doesn't work for me ([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11f01ceb-52a4-438f-b7ef-727ce7a3e191/atl-project-in-vs2010-rc-how-should-i-run-vs2010)).

To register COM .dll, use `regsvr32 /n /i:user "xxxx.dll"` ([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cf081f0-93e9-4a6f-a78c-dcebbcb9187e/peruser-redirection-atl-dll-doesnt-work)).